# Selenium Firefox webdriver won't load a blank page after changing Firefox preferences

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

everyone.

Main question: I am using the Python API for Selenium 2 and want to start a Firefox browser on a blank page (i.e. don't send any requests on browser startup). I created a FirefoxProfile object and changed 'browser.startup.page' to 0. The first time I create a webdriver using this profile it goes to mozilla.org but subsequent webdrivers start on a blank page like I intended. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Second question: the code below works fine when I enter it line by line in the interpreter but crashes when I try to run it as a script. I get a WebDriverException: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details." I also get a pop up window that says "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.". How can I fix this so that it runs as a script?

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
# Tell the browser to start on a blank page
profile.set_preference('browser.startup.page', 0)

# Start first session (doesn't work)
driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver1.close()
# Start second session (this works)
driver2 = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting "browser.startup.page" = 0 is the default for webdriver instances. The setting that works for me ([old FF defect](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102313))

```
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
```

A one-liner workaround without using a profile is to just load the empty page after starting the Firefox instance:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
driver.get("about:blank")
```

---

Oh, I forgot the 2nd part: The error message when running your code in a script is because the old Firefox instance is still running when you start the new one with the same profile. It takes some time to close the old browser window. If you add a *sleep* of 5 seconds before the last line in your sample, it works from a script too.

---

It was tricky to see why it worked without this on two of my machines. The reason: Iceweasel and the Firefox of Linux Mint do not show the update page.

BTW: Nice finding, that starting the next Firefox instance will work.

Comment: Great answer. This saved me a lot of time. Thanks!